# What does branchAndMerge function in Angular schematics do?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I'm experimenting with Angular schematics, and have encountered the function branchAndMerge() in various places. No one explains what it does, however.

Places I have seen it:

- [Generating Custom Code With The Angular CLI And Schematics](http://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/10/29/generating-custom-code-with-the-angular-cli-and-schematics.aspx)
- [amcdnl/material-schematics](https://github.com/amcdnl/material-schematics/blob/master/src/utils/devkit-utils/component.ts)
- [how to overwrite file with angular schematics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957132/how-to-overwrite-file-with-angular-schematics)
- [angular/devkit](https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts)

A clarification of how it differs from merge/mergeWith, and how to use it correctly would be appreciated.

P.S: Merge is  explained at [@angular-devkit/schematics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/schematics) as follows:

> Merge the input tree with the other Tree.

Btw I assume that merge() is now mergeWith, though I'm not 100% sure on that.

**Code example**

```
const rule = 
    // Creates a new rule that is a concatenation of other rules.
    chain([
      // Everyone uses it, but no one explains what it does...
      branchAndMerge(
        chain([
        // Merges the project tree with the virtual tree
        mergeWith(virtualTree)
      ]))
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [video](https://youtu.be/ZKyz0lb0GjA?t=30m21s) gives the best explanation I've heard of so far:

> Branch from current tree, and the tree is a virtual file system based
>   off of your current directory

If one were to look into the [code in the repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/src/tree/static.ts), one will see this is indeed the case. I would imagine the benefit of doing so, is for performance reasons, wherein it allows one to modify key/values instead of an actual hard disk. In addition, I would imagine it also simplifies process, as it makes the location irrelevant, which can greatly complicate process of schematics.